# How can I access W3C TraceContext Headers in a .net core 3.1 application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, trace, w3c

These sources ([microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation#enable-w3c-distributed-tracing-support-for-aspnet-core-apps), [microsoft dev blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/improvements-in-net-core-3-0-for-troubleshooting-and-monitoring-distributed-apps/)) state that in order to use the new [W3C Trace Context Headers](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/) in a .net 3.0+ core application no extra configuration is required. However, we are not receiving traceparent or tracestate from any request made via a ServiceClient.

What is the proper setup process? How did you guys get access to a distributed trace id? We prefer to expose those values automaticaly without adding a lot of code to all existing services, if that's possible.

Thank you very much in advance!

PS: this is my first question here; please let me know if you need further information

Comment: did you get any solution for the same . I am also not seeing trace identifer under the httpcontext even after following the above blogs and docs

Comment: No, not yet to be honest. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

The `System.Diagnostics.Activity` Id in .net 5 has already been configured as the [w3c standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/). It means that all `Actions` will be identifiable by a `traceparent` id format and both `traceparent` and `tracestate` will be sent to downstream dependencies in the `http` request header. As you said, no extra configuration is required, but in .net 3 is different, the default id format is the `Hierarchical` one and it's downstream propagated as a `HeaderRequestId`. To see the Activity Id format, import the `System.Diagnostics` to your class and type: `Console.WriteLine(Activity.Current.Id)`, you'll see a format like this: `|fab6082c-46326cca135ffe48.1.`. To change it to the w3c format in .net 3 is required to force it in your main method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Activity.DefaultIdFormat = ActivityIdFormat.W3C;
    Activity.ForceDefaultIdFormat = true;

    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

Then, you'll see w3c's format and also the `traceparent` and `tracestate` fields been propagated to the downstream dependencies in the header.

If you want to send messages throw a broker, use the `application-properties` section in case of [AMQP calls](https://w3c.github.io/trace-context-amqp/). You'll find some examples of both cases [here](https://github.com/luizhlelis/trace-context-w3c) and [here](https://github.com/luizhlelis/dotnet-trace-context).